# Differences at webpage in Linux and Windows

Tags: css, browser, fonts

I have a problem, because I want to use font as icons for menu items. I don't know why there's differences. Is it caused by `line-height` or `height`? You can view the code of wobit.vot.pl/cmstest/?page=test

Examples from browsershots:

[image]
and good:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the browser-zoom is same in both?

Comment: Most likely you refer to the vertical positioning of the icons on the left hand? Why don't you say so in your question? This has nothing to do with the operating system, most likely it is a different rendering result different browser engines produce when interpreting your style sheets. So you might want to read about positioning of icons by style rules and consult all those examples to be found out there on google.

Comment: When I add a background color to :before I see that icon is out of the element. Do you know why? In the past I haven't similar situation :/

Comment: You have 37 errors on your page. Different browsers respond differently to errors. Ergo, you get different results. Case closed.